# Make a figure blink/flash in jQuery

Tags: jquery

As it says in the title I was wondering if you can make a square or a circle blink/flash in jQuery? I already know how it works in CSS but the problem is that I can't call the CSS animation in jQuery, so long story short I need to make it blink/flash in jQuery. This is the whole code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset=utf-8 />
      <title>Conclusion2</title>
      <style>
        p {
           font-family: High Tower Text;
           font-size: 25px;
           margin-top: 0px;
           margin-bottom: 0px;
           margin-left: 0px;
           margin-right: 0px;
        }
      .first-child {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        background: white;
        border-radius: 0%;
        margin-top: 150px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-left: 500px;
        margin-right: 0px;
       -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s;
       animation: myfirst 1s;
      }
       @-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
          0% {background: white;}
         20% {background: white;}
         40% {background: white;}
         60% {background: white;}
         80% {background: white;}
        100% {background: red;}
      }
      .first-parent {
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-right: 0px;
      }
      .second-parent {
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-left: 415px;
        margin-right: 0px;
      }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
       <p>
         One of these figures will pop up for a short moment<br />
         Press the button to see how it works:
       </p>
       <div class="first-child"></div>

       <button class="first-parent" onclick="window.location.href='Conclusion3.html'">Next</button>

       <button class="second-parent" onclick="window.location.href='Conclusion2.html'">Click me !</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `I can't call the CSS animation in jQuery` - indeed, not directly. But you could put the animation in a separate CSS class and give `.first-child` that class when you want it to animate.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but what do u mean with "separate CSS class "?

Comment: why are you using a css animation just for changing the background color from white to red?

Comment: @kasperTaeymans because he wants to.

Comment: @kesperTaeymans Because I'm working on a "reaction test" that it needs to pop up a figure for a short moment. And then it's supposed to take the time from that moment when the animation stops until the user presses either B or R. So that's why I need it to pop up/flash.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

just assign the animation via jQuery like this:

```
//this will run on page load
$(function(){
    //target all 'p' elements
    //assign the animation
    $("p").css({
        "animation":"myfirst 1s",
        "-webkit-animation":"myfirst 1s"
    });
});
```

or, use jQuery animate with jQuery UI to animate the background color:

```js
$(function () {
    //set time out to fire after 800 milliseconds
    setTimeout(function () {
        //turn red, duration 100ms
        $("p").animate({
            backgroundColor: "red"
        }, 100, function () {
            //callback function, fires when the animate id done.
            //here we just call another animate to return color back to white
            $("p").animate({
                backgroundColor: "white"
            }, 100);
        });
    }, 800);
});
```

```css
p {
     font-family: High Tower Text;
     font-size: 25px;
     margin-top: 0px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-left: 0px;
     margin-right: 0px;
 }
 .first-child {
     height: 200px;
     width: 200px;
     background: white;
     border-radius: 0%;
     margin-top: 150px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-left: 500px;
     margin-right: 0px;
     -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s;
     animation: myfirst 1s;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
     0% {
         background: white;
     }
     20% {
         background: white;
     }
     40% {
         background: white;
     }
     60% {
         background: white;
     }
     80% {
         background: white;
     }
     100% {
         background: red;
     }
 }
 .first-parent {
     margin-top: 50px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-left: 100px;
     margin-right: 0px;
 }
 .second-parent {
     margin-top: 0px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-left: 415px;
     margin-right: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body>
    <p>One of these figures will pop up for a short moment
        <br />Press the button to see how it works:</p>
    <div class="first-child"></div>
    <button class="first-parent" onclick="window.location.href='Conclusion3.html'">Next</button>
    <button class="second-parent" onclick="window.location.href='Conclusion2.html'">Click me !</button>
</body>
```

**UPDATE:**

here is your code from the question animated using jQuery: <kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/r94h2xpv/)</kbd>

Comment: No sorry that was not what I meant, it's supposed to pop up a red square that is made in CSS but I need to make it do same thing but in jQuery

Comment: You didnt get my point, you dont have to animate the P, you can do it with the square instead. I just showed you an example of how animation is done with jquery, simply change the selector to target your square.

Comment: Aha ok thanks I will try the code and tell you if it did work or not !

Comment: alright :). if you need any explanation or clarification about my example, feel free to ask

Comment: yeah ok :) would you mind to send a complete code ? You know like in jsfiddle or in just in notepad or something, so it won't be any missunderstanding

Comment: sure, ill do it in a minute. you need the exact same code from your question just with jQuery ?

Comment: i have added the fiddle to the bottom of the answer